# need to split string from array with \n or \r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Dir.glob("**/*.xlsx") do |file|
 xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
 bookname = xlsx.column(1)

 tn = xlsx.column(4)
 tn_data = tn[1]
 p_tn_data = tn_data.split(/\r\n/)
 puts p_tn_data.class

 p_tn_data.to_s.each_line do |line|
  puts line
 end

 xlsx.column(3).each do |cl|
  if (cl != "Verse")
    directory_name = bookname[1]
    Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)
    output_name = "#{directory_name}/#{File.basename(cl[0], '.*')}.md"
    output = File.open(output_name, 'w')
    output << "hello"
    output.close
  end
 end
end
```

["The apostle John wrote this to Christians.\n• That which was from the beginning - The phrase “That which was from the beginning”\nrefers to Jesus, who existed before everything was made. You could translate this as “We\nare writing to you about the one who existed before the creation of all things.”\n• the beginning - “the beginning of all things” or “the creation of the world”\n• which we have heard - The phrase “which we have heard” refers to what Jesus taught\nthem. It can be translated as “We heard him teach.”\n• which we have seen with our eyes, which we have contemplated - “We ourselves have\nseen him.”\n• and our hands handled - “we have touched him with our hands”\n• the Word of life - This refers to Jesus. “He is the one who causes people to live forever.”\n• and was manifested to us - “but he came to live among us” (UDB)"]

> if you see in above array it is single string and there is "\n•", here \n is end of line and • is start line.
>
> > I have to make this array into all partial string not a single.

Answer (score 0):

Here: `p_tn_data = tn_data.split(/\r\n/)` you split the array on `\r\n` while the string itself contains only `\n`. Use ruby `\R` for this:

```
p_tn_data = tn_data.split(/\R+/)
```

Comment: Now Array length is showing 21 but my string is only 13.

Comment: p_tn_data = tn_data[2] // here string is not showing full string, i am counting string start with bullet only not line :(
puts p_tn_data.length

Comment: Let me remind: you have asked the question, titled “need to split string from array with `\n` or `\r`.” The code above perfectly answers the question stated. You have not shared neither input, nor intermediate results to make it possible to test the stuff on my side, but even if you were, I won’t do that; once again: the question stated is answered. Whether you have another question, post it separately.

Comment: I have poted another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243028/need-to-split-string-which-is-starting-with-bullet)