# Need to split string which is starting with bullet

Tags: ruby, string

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'roo'

Dir.glob("**/*.xlsx") do |file|
 xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
 bookname = xlsx.column(1)

 tn = xlsx.column(4)
 tn_data = tn[1]
 p_tn_data = tn_data.split(/\R+/)
 puts p_tn_data.[2]
 puts p_tn_data.length
end
```

Original string:

> ["Notes", "The apostle John wrote this to Christians.\n• That which was from the beginning - The phrase “That which was from the beginning”\nrefers to Jesus, who existed before everything was made. You could translate this as “We\nare writing to you about the one who existed before the creation of all things.”\n• the beginning - “the beginning of all things” or “the creation of the world”\n• we - In verses 1 and 2, the word “we” refers to John and those who knew Jesus when he\nwas on this earth, but it does not include the people John was writing to. (See: Exclusive)\n• which we have seen with our eyes, which we have contemplated - “We ourselves have\nseen him.”\n• the eternal life - This phrase also refers to Jesus, who causes us to live forever. It can be\ntranslated as “that he causes us to live forever.”\n• which was with the Father - “He was with God the Father”\n• and was manifested to us - “but he came to live among us” (UDB)"]

Output:

> TThe apostle John wrote this to Christians.
>   • That which was from the beginning - The phrase “That which was from the beginning”
>   refers to Jesus, who existed before everything was made. You could translate this as “We
>   are writing to you about the one who existed before the creation of all things.”
>   • the beginning - “the beginning of all things” or “the creation of the world”
>   • we - In verses 1 and 2, the word “we” refers to John and those who knew Jesus when he
>   was on this earth, but it does not include the people John was writing to. (See: Exclusive)
>   • which we have seen with our eyes, which we have contemplated - “We ourselves have
>   seen him.”
>   • the eternal life - This phrase also refers to Jesus, who causes us to live forever. It can be
>   translated as “that he causes us to live forever.”
>   • which was with the Father - “He was with God the Father”
>   • and was manifested to us - “but he came to live among us” (UDB)

`p_tn_data.length` is showing 13 but my data is only 7 (I am counting only string which start with bullet like `•`)

Comment: Please, provide more information in what you want to achieve. You need to split how? You need the dot to be part of it? You need to split only by the dot. Make your question clearer.

Comment: I need string which is start from bullet. That is only 7, so array index should be [0 to 6].